# Consciousness/body hopping

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I am looking for a sci-fi novel about people moving their consciousness into other persons, 'swapping' so you can experience others lives, then getting trapped into anothers body, and trying to get back original body, being able to experience first hand others' experiences, and plot twists such as a female arm wrestling a male and winning a bet.

Comment: Was it a series of short stories or a novel?

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. When did you read it? Do you remember anything else about the main characters? How did they swap bodies? Did they use "blanks" or were people required to swp in pairs?

Comment: “plot twists such as a female arm wrestling a male and winning a bet.” Plot twist? That does happen in real life. Well, if you’re me.

Comment: The arm-wrestling part rules out Sheckley's *Mindswap*.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like the novel "Hopscotch" by Kevin J. Anderson.

I don't specifically remember the part about arm-wrestling. But, the basic premise definitely fits:

"Suppose you could switch bodies with another person? What exciting new experiences would you choose to explore? What forbidden desires would you indulge? Suppose someone stole your life-how far would you go to get it back?"

[Fantastic Fiction](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/a/kevin-j-anderson/hopscotch.htm)

[image: Cover 1]

Comment: Yes, that's it. The arm-wrestling match is between Teresa and Meroni and it's described in chapter 68.

Comment: A Kevin J. Anderson novel, huh? Why is the OP asking for its name? So he can consciously avoid ever coming across it again?